# Is there an achievement in Portal 2 like Portal's Transmission Received?

Tags: achievements, portal-2

Similar to the previous Portal's achievement, do you get an achievement in Portal 2 for bringing a radio along to certain points?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is one achievement, Final Transmission, for one radio.

> Specifically, test with all the garbage (Chapter 2, Test 6) has a radio in it, and one of Rat Man's dens. Take it there for an achievement.

Additional info:

> Like the radios in Portal 1, the secret message decodes into 3 SSTV images which show details about the original Portal ARG, revealing the budget was about $100 and that the 'test subjects' took about half an hour longer than they expected.

Comment: didnt check the spoiler but checked some listings and i think it should be "final" not "hidden". but thanks for the heads up :)

Comment: @corroded You're right, fixed it.